# No longer sci-fi technology?

Tags: technology

After watching Promethius the other day, and noting that much of the human technology seemed like stuff we have today, or could obtained quite soon. Except interstellar travel and maybe the hovering aspect of the cave mapping probes.

This got me to wonder, if there are any pure sci-fi movies (not including e.g. James Bond kind of sci-fi), that if evaluated today could be considered no longer sci-fi? That is, the answer I'm looking for is:

Movie name:

- Example of sci-fi technology 1 - today's real technology that is
  basically the same thing.
- Example of sci-fi technology 2 ...

I've tried to come up with any reasonable example but can't think of any.

Comment: As noted in the FAQ, questions asking for lists are off-topic for this site.

Comment: I was a bit afraid of that, reading the FAQ though I thought it could be OK since I didn't really want a list of movies but just a movie that would fulfill the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2001 A Space Odyssey**

- Flights to the moon? Check.
- Space ports? [Check](http://www.virgingalactic.com/).
- Video Phone? Check.
- [Laptops/Tablets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acznH.png)? Check.
- AI that can do most of what HAL does? Check, although not all in one thing yet.
- Being able to fly to Jupiter? Check.

Aside from the fantasy elements, I don't know of anything in 2001 we haven't done. Some not on the same scale yet, but we will, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

**A Trip to the Moon**

I don't think you are going to find a whole movie or story that answers your question. Perception of what is SCI-FI change, in early Heinlein stories they navigated spaces ships using books of Logarithm tables! And people *still* write SCI-FI where space ships have pilots.

Comment: I don't think humanity will ever get to a completely pilotless spaceship.  We will never trust the machines or computers enough to let them do it all.  Even though, using today's technology on the newest aircraft, one could let a plane fly completely by itself from leaving the gate at one airport to parking at the gate at another using nothing but autopilot.

Comment: @BBlake Autopilot can't deal with surprises or unknowns very well, and requires a lot of extra equipment at the airport to be able to land the plane.  Perceptions change over time, and [driverless cars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_driverless_car) may eventually become common despite saying the same thing about them today.

Comment: But I cringe every time someone( usually a single person) docks The Enterprise on manual. It's just not going to happen.

Comment: Which is why we still have pilots.  But I could dock the Enterprise manually.  I'm just that good.